# UITableView Custom cells, built of UIViews, can be concurrent?

Tags: ios, uitableview, concurrency

I am building my cellViews like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString* cellIdentifier=@"cell";

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    UIImageView cellView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rectCellFrame];

    NSError* error=nil;
    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageArray[indexPath.row] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

    UIImage* theImage= [UIImage ImageWithData:imageData];

    [cellView setImage:theImage];

    [cell addSubView:cellView];

    .
    .
    .
    .

    [cell addSubView:moreViews];

}
```

Since the loading time (even when the images are cached) is very slow, I need to make this concurrent. But I would like to still be using my code with UIViews/UIImageViews.
Is there a way for me to show a placeholder and when relevant, ie cellView is finished building from all subviews, update the image instead of the placeholder?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can set up all the heavy slow code in a asynchronous task. It's often down when images need to be downloaded. I'm sure it's covered in at least 1 of the WWDC videos on Table Views, but I've no clue which one or how old it would be by now.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // place holder image for the moment
    [cellView setImage:placeHolderImage];

    // run code to get the real image in asynchronous task 
    dispatch_async(self.contextQueue, ^{
        UIImage *realImage = [thingy imageFromTimeConsumingTask];
        // update cell on main thread (you need to do all UI stuff on main thread)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cellView setImage:realImage];
        });
    });
}
```